# How to do fast modulo arithmetik of large numbers on 32-bit maschines?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

if we choose two random values $a,b<p$, where $p$ is a prime of 15360 bits. The typical way to store such values is to store it as a short[960] array. The addition and multiplication then is defined with carry. But how could we implement a modulo arithmetik? Say we want to avoid to store short[$960\cdot 2$], how could I do this then?

That means we're doing like this:

Let $a_i,b_i$ the array entries, then we do in pseudo-code:

```
uint carry;
for(i){
   uint c_i = (uint) a_i + (uint) b_i;
   set(c_i, carry); //stores in c_i the (short) entry and carries the overflow to the next turn.
}
```

Edit: Let me try to explain this at a mathematics level.

This is basically a sum of arguments reduced to an common basis $B$, therefore, we could write it, as
$c=(c_0,...,c_n)$, where $c_k = (a_k+b_k + carry_k)B^k$ and $carry_0=0, carry_k = a_k+b_k\bmod B$ (in our case $B=2^{16}$ and $n=1920$.) Since we like compute the remainder modulo $p$, where $p$ has $r$ Bits of length ($\sim2^r$), how could we implement that reduction into thus calculations? Do we have to do a long division?

Comment: You didn't say the problem exactly you're doing, is it just a mod b? Or a+b mod p? Either way you are reinventing the wheel and you are on the wrong stack exchange.

Comment: It is about "a+b mod p". Which stackexchange would be recommended, in your view, for that problem? I do not want to reinvent the wheel, but I'm on my way to understand how the typical solutions work, or how someone could implement such solutions.

Comment: @Ian I added a mathematical description, on what I'm looking for. :)

Comment: there was a subject called "error free computation" that came and sort of disappeared. You might want to hunt it down and check it out.